# android create horizontal date picker

Tags: android, listview, datepicker, android-viewpager, android-custom-view

I want to create a date picker like this in my application:
[sample date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnjvH.png)

that a font size of center text is larger than other and when user scroll left or right the text of view changes and user can select any date simply.

how can I do?

Comment: Use three horizontal `RecyclerViews`, vertically stacked.

Comment: i think `RecyclerView` isn't answer because as i said the font size of center text is larger than others

Comment: You are welcome to render your `RecyclerView` items however you want. If you want the center one to have a larger font size, go right ahead.

Comment: can you help me please to implement `RecyclerView` with this feature?

Comment: Off the cuff, I would expect that you need to create your own `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`, perhaps extending `LinearLayoutManager`, to handle your fixed number of visible items and highlight of the center item. Or take a look at the [many existing date picker libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27), find one that is close, and see if you can modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Is viewpager useful in this case?

Comment: That is another possibility, using [one of the techniques to show multiple pages at once](https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html).